# How to Disable script handling in IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-server, upload

I have an ASP.net web site that allows users to upload files to an upload folder on the server. The site is served by IIS 7.

I have configured the upload folder to not execute any script files that are requested, but how can I configure IIS 7 to serve these files as it would any other static file ONLY for this folder?

Thanks

## EDIT

Here is what I have in the Handler Mappings for my upload folder:

[image: Handler Mappings]

Here is the web.config for the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read">
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <remove name="SSINC-shtml" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-Integrated" />
        <remove name="AXD-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="ASPClassic" />
        <remove name="AssemblyResourceLoader-Integrated" />
        <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-Integrated" />
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <remove name="ScriptResource" />
        <remove name="SSINC-shtm" />
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="SSINC-stm" />
        <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
        <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
        <remove name="SecurityCertificate" />
        <remove name="TraceHandler-Integrated" />
        <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
        <remove name="WebAdminHandler-Integrated" />
        <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
        <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-soap-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="HttpRemotingHandlerFactory-rem-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="CGI-exe" />            
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is what I get if I request an aspx file that is in my upload folder:

> Server Error
> 404 - File or directory not found.
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a mime type for the file that I want to serve.

I used * to serve unknown file types as application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a web.config file in this directory that un-maps all the handlers and map "*" to static:

```
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
```